# Best place to ask Jenkins/Groovy related qustions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Can anyone tell me where the best place to discuss Jenkins related stuff is?

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to ask here for specific questions.

https://jenkins.io/participate/ also lists two resources: mailing lists and IRC.